# i wanted to add custmised package properties into android xml layout?Here "VerticalMarqueeTextView" is class in my custamised package

Tags: android

```
 <android.lib.verticalmarqueetextview.VerticalMarqueeTextView
        android:layout_height="0dp";
        example:marqueeSpeed="25";
        example:textSize="20dp"
        example:textColor="@android:color/white"
        example:textStyle="bold"
        example:text="some text" />
```

Here "VerticalMarqueeTextView" is class in my dereived package, i am not able to get those properties into xml layout

Answer (score 0):

**Try this way,hope this will help you to solve your problem.**

```
<android.lib.verticalmarqueetextview.VerticalMarqueeTextView
    xmlns:example="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android.lib.verticalmarqueetextview"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    example:marqueeSpeed="25"
    example:textSize="20dp"
    example:textColor="@android:color/white"
    example:textStyle="bold"
    example:text="some text" />
```

Comment: can you please accept and upvote ans so it may help other to solve same problem.